Calculate the range of $a$ and prove $x_1 + x_2 > 2$ for two solutions of $e ^ x - x\ln x - ax - 1 = 0$
Given
$$ f(x) = e ^ x - x\ln x - ax - 1 $$(a belongs to R $a\in \mathbb{R}$), has two zero point
($f(x_1) = 0$ $f(x_2) = 0$).
(1) calculate the range of $a$
(2) Prove that : $$x_1 + x_2 > 2$$
My attempt:
[]


Did you even try to find the solution?

@Gwen yes, but it takes time to translate it and upload it by formatting it. Let me upload the script firstly.

Wow you have a good handwriting

You are saying $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and asking for its range. What does that mean?

@CroCo a should have a shadow range : $a > e - 1$

Your argument 当$x=0$ is not proper.

@FrancisBacon Is it something like homework assignment? If so, the solutions should not be very complicated.

@MathArt x mustn't be 0 since $lnx$ exists

@RiverLi If it is not complicated, could you help find the solution?

@FrancisBacon I think your approach works, i.e.. to prove that $g(x) \ge g(2-x)$ for all $0 < x \le 1$. I don't have a simple solution. So I asked you if it is a homework assignment.

Proceed along OP's lines
Let
$g(x) := \frac{\mathrm{e}^x - 1}{x} - \ln x$.
We have $g'(x) = \frac{(x-1)(\mathrm{e}^x - 1)}{x^2}$.
Note that $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, 1)$, and strictly increasing on $(1, \infty)$,
and $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} g(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = \infty$.
Thus, when $a > g(1) = \mathrm{e} - 1$, $g(x) = a$ has exactly two positive real solutions $0 < x_1 < 1 < x_2$. We need to prove that $x_1 + x_2 > 2$.
It suffices to prove that $x_2 > 2 - x_1$.
Since $g(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(1, \infty)$,
it suffices to prove that $g(x_2) > g(2 - x_1)$.
Using $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$, it suffices to prove that $g(x_1) > g(2-x_1)$ for all $0 < x_1 < 1$, i.e.
$$F(x_1) := \frac{\mathrm{e}^{x_1} - 1}{x_1} - \ln x_1
- \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2-x_1} - 1}{2-x_1} + \ln(2 - x_1) > 0.$$
Since $F(1) = 0$, it suffices to prove that $F'(x_1) < 0$ on $(0, 1)$. We have
$$F'(x_1) = \frac{(x_1-1)(\mathrm{e}^{x_1}x_1^2 - \mathrm{e}^{2-x_1}x_1^2 - 4\mathrm{e}^{x_1} x_1 + 4\mathrm{e}^{x_1} + 4x_1-4)}{x_1^2(2-x_1)^2}.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$G(x_1) := \mathrm{e}^{x_1}x_1^2 - \mathrm{e}^{2-x_1}x_1^2 - 4\mathrm{e}^{x_1} x_1 + 4\mathrm{e}^{x_1} + 4x_1-4 > 0.$$
Since $G(0) = G(1) = 0$, it suffices to prove that
$G''(x_1) < 0$ on $(0, 1)$, i.e.
$$-(2 - x_1^2)\mathrm{e}^{x_1} - (x_1^2 - 4x_1 + 2)\mathrm{e}^{2-x_1} < 0,$$
or
$$-(2 - x_1^2)\mathrm{e}^{2x_1} - (x_1^2 - 4x_1 + 2)\mathrm{e}^{2} < 0.$$
Using $\mathrm{e}^{x_1}= \mathrm{e}\mathrm{e}^{x_1-1}
\ge \mathrm{e}(1 + x_1-1) \ge 0 $, it suffices to prove that
$$-(2 - x_1^2)(\mathrm{e}x_1)^2 - (x_1^2 - 4x_1 + 2)\mathrm{e}^{2} < 0$$
which is true.
We are done.

$$-(2 - x_1^2)(\mathrm{e}x_1)^2 - (x_1^2 - 4x_1 + 2)\mathrm{e}^{2} < 0$$,
Why this is true, it seems complicated

@FrancisBacon It is $\mathrm{e}^2(x_1^4 - 3x_1^2 + 4x_1 - 2) < 0$. If you use rational root theorem, it is $\mathrm{e}^2(x_1 - 1)(x_1^3 + x_1^2 - 2x_1 + 2) < 0$.

@Could you explain more? Still do not get it.

@FrancisBacon Do you mean how to prove $-(2 - x_1^2)(\mathrm{e}x_1)^2 - (x_1^2 - 4x_1 + 2)\mathrm{e}^{2} < 0$?

yes, and how you come up with using $\mathrm{e}^{x_1}= \mathrm{e}\mathrm{e}^{x_1-1}
\ge \mathrm{e}(1 + x_1-1) \ge 0 $. It looks magic to me.

@FrancisBacon Using $\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\mathrm{e}^{x_1-1} \ge 1 + x_1 - 1 = x_1$. Thus, $\mathrm{e}^{x_1} \ge ex_1$.

$$e2({1}−1)({1}^3+{1}^2−2{1}+2)$$, how to apply rational root theorem to get the 1 as a zero point? Does it include a lot of calculations?

@FrancisBacon For rational root theorem, see: https://brilliant.org/wiki/rational-root-theorem/. Now, can you find that $1$ is a rational root of $x_1^4 - 3x_1^2 + 4x_1 - 2 = 0$?

Here is my understanding: x=+-1, +2, among then, only 1 will make the $^4−3^2+4−2=0$ be zero, so it is the ratinal root, and use x -1 to factoring（因式分解）

@FrancisBacon Yes, it is.
